# Tracing a Route on a Map

Tags: r

I am working with the R programming language.

Using OSM (Open Street Maps), I am trying to make a detailed map for the city of Toronto (Canada) with the road distance between the CN Tower and the Toronto Airport.

Here is what I have so far:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(sf)
library(osm)
library(osmdata)

pt1 <- st_point(c(-79.41203, 43.64312))  # CN Tower
pt2 <- st_point(c(-79.62683, 43.67772))  # Toronto Airport


pts <- st_sfc(pt1, pt2, crs = 4326)


bbox <- st_bbox(pts)


osm_features <- c("motorway", "trunk", "primary", "secondary", "tertiary", "residential", "path", "waterway", "natural")


osm_data <- opq(bbox = bbox) %>%
    add_osm_feature(key = 'highway', value = osm_features) %>%
    osmdata_sf()


ggplot() +
    geom_sf(data = osm_data$osm_lines, color = "gray40") +
    geom_sf(data = osm_data$osm_polygons, fill = "lightblue") +  # Water bodies in light blue
    geom_sf(data = pts, color = "red", size = 3) +
    coord_sf(xlim = c(bbox$xmin, bbox$xmax), ylim = c(bbox$ymin, bbox$ymax)) +
    theme_minimal()
```

Unfortunately, I don't think what I have done is correct. First off, one of these red points seems to be quite isolated from the rest of the map, leading me to believe that the placement is not correct. Secondly, I am still unable to trace the road path between these two red points.

Can someone please show me what I am doing wrong and what I can do to fix this?

Thanks!

[image]

**UPDATE 1:** Using the suggestion provided by @Spacedman:

```
pt1 <- st_point(c(-79.41203, 43.64312))  # CN Tower
pt2 <- st_point(c(-79.62683, 43.67772))  # Toronto Airport

pts <- st_sfc(pt1, pt2, crs = 4326)

bb <- st_bbox(st_buffer(pts, 10000))

osm_features <- c("motorway", "trunk", "primary", "secondary", "tertiary", "residential", "path", "waterway", "natural")

osm_data <- opq(bbox = bb) %>%
    add_osm_feature(key = 'highway', value = osm_features) %>%
    osmdata_sf()

ggplot() +
    geom_sf(data = osm_data$osm_lines, color = "gray40") +
    geom_sf(data = osm_data$osm_polygons, fill = "lightblue") +  # Water bodies in light blue
    geom_sf(data = pts, color = "red", size = 3) +
    coord_sf(xlim = c(bb$xmin, bb$xmax), ylim = c(bb$ymin, bb$ymax)) +
    theme_minimal()
```

[image]

**UPDATE 2:**

```
library(osrm)


pt1_coords <- st_coordinates(pt1)
pt2_coords <- st_coordinates(pt2)

route <- osrmRoute(src = pt1_coords, dst = pt2_coords, overview = "full")

route_df <- data.frame(st_coordinates(route$geometry))


ggplot() +
    geom_sf(data = osm_data$osm_lines, color = "gray40") +
    geom_sf(data = osm_data$osm_polygons, fill = "lightblue") +  # Water bodies in light blue
    geom_sf(data = pts, color = "red", size = 3) +
    geom_path(data = route_df, aes(X,Y), color="blue", size=1.5) +
    coord_sf(xlim = c(bb$xmin, bb$xmax), ylim = c(bb$ymin, bb$ymax)) +
    theme_minimal()
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Check with an online map. The red point top left is Toronto Airport, but all its roads approach from the north, so you haven't included them by using the bounding box to get the OSM data.

Expand the bounding box by a bit until its big enough to pick out the roads out of the airport, then you'll have something connected you can do routing with.

Comment: thank you so much for your answer! if you have time, can you please show me how to do this? Thanks!

Comment: You could buffer the bounding box by a few km and try again. I won't go through route finding because that should be explained elsewhere.

Comment: Or buffer the points - `bb = st_bbox(st_buffer(pts, 10000))` for a 10km buffer which should be enough, I'm not sure what the scale is at this point.

Comment: thank you so much for your reply! I have updated my question with your answer in case anyone in the future wants to see the complete solution. Is it also possible to trace the road path on the map here?

Comment: Have you done that with Update 2? You shouldn't answer your own question in the question - do it by making an Answer!

Comment: thank you for your reply! I made an update to the question because I was not confident that the answer I provided was correct.

Comment: can you please add your "magic touch" to my R code if you have time?

Comment: I don't understand - you've got the route as the blue line on the map. What more needs doing?